# Issues with KML Layers limit

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, checkbox

I have loaded 6 kml layers via url to my website to be toggled off/on by checkboxes.  I have recently notice though, that it will only allow me to show 4 kml's at a given time.  When I select more than 4 the 5th and 6th does not show.  It does not matter what ones I choose, it seems to limit me to only showing 4.  Can someone direct me on what may be causing this or should I be coding this some other way?  The kml's by themselves do work and are under 800kb.  Is just seems very weird that I can only have 4 kml showing at a given time.

This is the site - www.gbnrtc.org/bikemap

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [KML Support page](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport), which lists the level of KML support provided for Google Maps and Google Maps for mobile, it lists the following size and complexity restrictions:

- **Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ): 3MB**
- Maximum uncompressed KML file size: 10MB
- Maximum number of Network Links: 10
- Maximum number of total document-wide features: 1,000

Given that you estimate your file size at ~800K, that would put you right around 3.2 MB for four of your files. Without knowing more about your KML content, it seems to make sense that the limit would gate you after loading four.

Comment: I did read that and was assuming that the individual files should not be over 3MB not that combined total of the 6 files is where this comes into play. But even combining the total of all 6 kmls my overall total is exactly 1.37MB.  The 800kb is just the largest of the 6 kmls.

Comment: Ok, well that isn't your problem. Are you approaching any of the other restrictions?

Comment: I don't not believe so, I am at this point switching my kmls over to fusion tables and see if that will get me pass a restriction that I am unaware of.  Everything seemed to be working but this last week I have noticed this where just 4 kmls are showing. All in all my application is I believe small, at this point I am just going through the code again to make sure I did not code something the wrong way. But it seems that 4 is the magic number for some reason.

Comment: Side note just double checked code and its 8 layers totaling 1.33mb and the number shown is limited to 6 not 4.  I just saw that there has been a google ticket about this issue.

Comment: Do you have information on the ticket? You should add it to your question or I can add it to the answer - probably best in your question. Thanks for follow-up -

Comment: This was where I found out about the ticket.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835276/google-maps-number-of-kml-layers-limit

Comment: As of Sunday this issue-bug "4185" has been fixed.  My own application is working now.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite old. I have found a great library to load large KML/KMZ files (even if Google is throwing an error). Please note that the library is quite old and have not received any update.

Here are more details about it:

Using **GeoXML**, I was able to add all the required KMLs to the map successfully! https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3

Step 1: Download and include geoxml3.js script

```
<script src="geoxml3.js"></script> // include after google map api script
```

Stpe 2: Instantiate and initialize the object in JS:

```
var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
myParser.parse('/path/to/data.kml');
```

And this will load the KMl file.