# Google Maps Number of KML layers limit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We used to be able to display 7 KML layers on google map. But now it's only possible to show 5 layers. It's documented:

> You can use the Maps API to add up to five Fusion Tables layers to a map, one of which can be >styled with up to five styling rules.

But I didn't see similar limit for KML layers. Is this a undocumented new change?

More detail: 
The layers are toggled with checkboxes, when all 7 checkboxes are checked, only the first 5 layers are shown. If I hide the first layer, the sixth layer will immediately show.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is a recently introduced bug, and I've filed a ticket to fix it up.

Comment: This was a bug in the way KML was rendered, and a fix for this rolled out last week.  It seems to work correctly now but please update if there's still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug may still be there or maybe back in a different form. I am trying to load 27 kml files (total size 77.6 kb - well under the limit) and it seems to only be able to load 25 - if I turn off two layers using the dropdown the map loads fine. See http://www.trammaps.com/Map.html,

Regards,

Lea.