# limit to combination of Fusion Table layers and KML layers in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-fusion-tables

This earlier question relates to mine
[Google Maps Number of KML layers limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835276/google-maps-number-of-kml-layers-limit)
, but I'm trying to find out if there is some sort of a limit on maps combining Fusion Table layers and KML layers.

I have a map (http://openlandsmaps.org/GIS1/html/Community_Greening/Visioning/OpenlandsCookVisioning12.html)
 within the 5 Fusion Table layer limit which incorporates additional KML layers. These layers toggle on and off with check boxes. I cannot get the final two layers in the list to display, though they display fine when their code is isolated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question. Not just a link to the problem page (which will eventually go away).

Answer (score 0):

I get errors in your code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: park is not defined OpenlandsCookVisioning12.html:186
Uncaught ReferenceError: GreenHealth is not defined OpenlandsCookVisioning12.html:94
Uncaught ReferenceError: TreeKeeper is not defined OpenlandsCookVisioning12.html:104
```

There is a limit on KmlLayer based on the total length of all the URLs passed into the class (but that isn't your problem).  Your problem is the first error. "park" is not defined in this line:

```
park.setMap(null);
```

that line should be:

```
Acc77.setMap(null);
```

the lines following that which define the GreenHealth layer and the TreeKeeper layer are not executed due to the error.

To address the KmlLayer limit question, from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport):

> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. 
>   If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will display. The limit is based on the total 
>   length of all URLs passed to the KMLLayer class, and consequently will vary by application; 
>   on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without hitting the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help. Something I probably should have caught.